# Can GetObject do this?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently working on developing a macro that will input various forms into an access database.

Due to the nature of the beast of this program, I've had to split my main program into two sub programs and call them, but I need to use getobject to call a file path twice now.

I use getobject to open a file, and then use myrec.fields(~column name~) = xlsht.cells(1, "a") to populate various column values. I'm unsure if there are other "efficient" ways to accomplish this.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a variable in place of the filepath with the GetObject command, instead of needing to manually replace the file path in the code.

I've tested a fair amount of different code, including the path, class functionality but I don't think I understand VBA enough to truly make the best use of that.

I can make it work using this

```vb
Dim XL As Variant
Dim XLApp As Variant
Dim XLsht As Variant
Dim XLwrkbk As Variant

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XLwrkbk = GetObject(~file path~)
Set XLsht = XLwrkbk.Worksheets(1)
Set MyRec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("database name")
```

Ideally I would like it to be

```
Dim filename As String
Dim XL As Variant
Dim XLApp As Variant
Dim XLsht As Variant
Dim XLwrkbk As Variant

filename = " ~insert file path~ "

Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XLwrkbk = GetObject(filename)
Set XLsht = XLwrkbk.Worksheets(1)
Set MyRec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("database name")
```

I receive a run time error

Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
    Dim XL As New Excel.Application, Filename As String

    Filename = "~ your file ~"

    XL.Workbooks.Open (Filename)
    myrec.fields(~column name~) = XL.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").value
```

Comment: I don't entirely know if this works how I need it to, I did update my post with more information as I realized that I didn't explain what it was I am doing with that data. 

Maybe that helps?

Comment: You don't need GetObject to just get value of **A1** cell. I updated my answer.